# How to get Longitude and latitude from SqLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps

Hi guys  I have a database with latitude and longitude. I want to putthose values (latitude and longitude) from my database to my variable `TUJUAN`. I tried with this code but I don't know how to query from my database..  Here is my code

```
public class Arahkan extends FragmentActivity{
static public LatLng TUJUAN;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.arahkan);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
            this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    // Open the database
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }


    TextView arahkantext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_arah2);

    String tampilarah = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    if(tampilarah.equalsIgnoreCase("Balong Dalem")){
        tempat="Balong Dalem";
    }
    if(tampilarah.equalsIgnoreCase("Curug Bangkong")){
        tempat="CUrug Bangkong"
    }
           .........
           Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(
       "SELECT latlng FROM data WHERE nama_tempat='"  + tempat +  "';", null);  I DONT KNOW IN THIS LINE
            TUJUAN = new LatLng(???); ///  I DONT KNOW IN THIS LINE
```

}

Comment: Please don't do blocking operations on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

How is stored your LatLng? You should store the two values (latitude and longitude), so that you can create a new LatLng based on those values that way:

```
c.moveToFirst();
maCourse = new LatLng(c.getInt(0), c.getInt(1);
```

Assuming that your first store Latitude, then Longitude
If I'd have to link you to a good tutorial about databases, I'd say this one: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html